# Why the need of Sobolev spaces in this proof of isoperimetric inequality?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

I was reading the chapter about isoperimetric inequalities in DaCorogna's book "Introduction to The Calculus of Variations". The isoperimetric inequality is proved to be equivalent to Wirtinger Inequality. At page 154, he introduces Wirtinger inequality in this way:

Let
$$X=\{u \in W^{1,2} : u(-1)=u(1) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \int_{-1}^1 u(x) \, dx = 0\}$$.
Then
$$\int_{-1}^{1} u^{'\, 2} \, dx \geq \pi^2 \int_{-1}^{1} u^2 \, dx, \  \forall \, u \in X.$$

I'm new to Sobolev spaces and my question is: why, exactly, the need to introduce Sobolev space as the $X$ of choice?

Comment: Do you need some sort of further explanation?

Comment: Pardon, I forgot about the question. I don't know about your answer. For once, $C^\infty$ is never even mentioned in the proof itself. Plus I thought the real reason was something less general and more related to calculus of variations, where I see Sobolev spaces mentioned as the space of choice in which to look for minimizers of particolar functionals. I think it has something to do with the properties of the space itself?

Comment: Perhaps $C^\infty$ is never mentioned but maybe $C^1$ is? How did the proof go? The proof I've seen first shows the result for some nice class of functions and then extends to Sobolev functions by a density argument.

Comment: Yup, that's how it goes. First it is proved for a function in $X \cap C^2[-1,1]$ using Fourier series, then it's extended by a density argument. So the introduction of $W^{1,2}$ is just to extend the result to the maximum generality?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You prove it for $X\cap C^2$, then you observe: (1) $X\cap C^2$ is dense in $X$, and (2) the integrals over compact domains are continuous with respect to the Sobolev norm, so you can conclude by density.

Comment: Ok, got it, though I was hoping in something more interesting. Thank your for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *need* to introduce Sobolev spaces, but the point here is that $W^{1,2}$ is the completion of $C^\infty$ with the norm $\|f\|_{W^{1,2}}:=\|f\|_{L^2}+\|f'\|_{L^2}$. So if you prove the above inequality for all smooth $f$ with appropriate conditions, then by continuity of the integral you automatically have the result for all $f\in W^{1,2}$.